# Best place to load current IdentityUser for custom UserService?

Tags: c#, dependencies, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity

**My goal**

This is a Blazor Server project. Due to multi-tenancy reasons, I regularly want to retrieve a *TenantId* for the logged in user so that I can run correct queries using EF Core.

To keep it all 'DRY' I want to avoid Injecting *AuthenticationStateProvider* & *UserManager<>* in every component to retreive the current user.

**My approach**

I have my *ApplicationUser* with the needed properties all working fine:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; } = default!;

        public int TenantId { get; set; } = default!

        // And so on..
    }
```

I've created a class called *UserService*, I inject this service into each component to easily perform user tasks like getting the current user (and *TenantId*):

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
        public ApplicationUser CurrentUser { get; private set; } = default!;

        private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;
        
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
                
        public UserService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;

            InitialiseCurrentUserAsync().Wait();
        }

        private async Task InitialiseCurrentUserAsync()
        {
            var authstate = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            CurrentUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(authstate.User.Claims.Skip(1).First().Value);
        }
}
```

This Service is scoped in my 'Program.cs':

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>()
```

My components can now easily use the current *ApplicationUser* like this:

```
[Inject]
public IUserService UserService { get; set; } = default!;

private List<Foo> _foo = new List<Foo>();

private async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        _foo = await FooRepository.GetBarAsync(UserService.CurrentUser.TenantId);

       ...
    }
```

**My Problem**

Although the code in the *components* now looks clean and 'DRY', the *constructor* of the *UserService* does **not**.
I don't think I should get the *ApplicationUser* through the *UserService constructor*.

In fact, once I use *Roles* by adding `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` to the *IdentityBuilder*, the application keeps loading endlessly. The *InitialiseCurrentUserAsync()* task doesn't complete.

Where should I load the current ApplicationUser?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a deadlock because of this line `InitialiseCurrentUserAsync().Wait();`. Edit your solution to be like this:

```
private async Task<string> InitialiseCurrentUserAsync()
    {
        var authstate = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        return await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(authstate.User.Claims.Skip(1).First().Value);
    }

 public UserService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
  {
    //.....
    CurrentUser = InitialiseCurrentUserAsync()
                 .ConfigureAwait(false)
                 .GetAwaiter()
                 .GetResult();
  }
```

Comment: First of all, thanks. Never knew about ".ConfigureAwait(false)". As with my code, your code works fine when I don't use Roles. As soon as i start using Roles "return await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(authstate.User.Claims.Skip(1).First().Value);" will await forever. I'll have to gain more knowledge about Identity. I still kind of think this is a design problem, that I shouldn't fetch the user from the constructor, but I don't know of a good alternative either.